# yocto fails to build images for intel edison in ubuntu 17.10(64 bit)

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, intel-edison, ubuntu-17.10

I am beginner to yocto. I am trying to build edison images on ubuntu 17.10.

I am following [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/593591) link.

But It fails in native autmake.

I have linked [recipe ERROR](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xvi4I_7Z0uaWUubwn5meNu6RyE_A_PMa) over here.

## RE-EDIT

I have made changes for removing automake error, followed by [patch](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=blob;f=tools/automake/patches/010-automake-port-to-Perl-5.22-and-later.patch;h=31b9273d547145e5ecbeaef20a1e82cc9292fdc2;hb=92c80f38cff3c20388f9ac13d5196f2745aeaf77).
Now it's failed in native ncurses-5.9. Log file is attached [Log_file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mQddgaY0P_JTVcepnXzGADQuVXFZWFcI).

Thanks,

Pritam

Comment: Advice: it's much better to include steps and error output in concise manner to question. Therefore it will be search-able and valid if links will be dead. As for the matter: do you have the same error persistent or it goes away when you run build again? Or when you "bitbake -c cleanall automake-native" and then build again?

Comment: Yes, it's persisted. But after doing, cleanall automake-native, "WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-17.10" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution." with error "ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:
"

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: I would highly recommend to look to this site: https://github.com/htot/meta-intel-edison/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with generation man docs for automake in the command line:

```
: && /bin/mkdir -p doc && { PATH='/home/prityaa/documents/boards/intel/edison/tools/yocto/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/build_edison/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.14.1-r0/build/t/wrap':$PATH && export PATH; } && /usr/bin/perl /home/prityaa/documents/boards/intel/edison/tools/yocto/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/build_edison/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.14.1-r0/automake-1.14.1/doc/help2man --output=doc/automake-1.14.1 automake-1.14
```

The real error is not printed but just truncated to:

```
help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.14
```

You can follow advice to:

```
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
```

but I don't think you really want generate automake docs so much :)

So, I suggest just workaround it with creating fake output docs to please the make. Run on your machine :

```
$ touch /home/prityaa/documents/boards/intel/edison/tools/yocto/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/build_edison/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.14.1-r0/automake-1.14.1/doc/automake-1.14.1
$ touch /home/prityaa/documents/boards/intel/edison/tools/yocto/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/iot-devkit-yp-poky-edison-20160606/build_edison/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.14.1-r0/automake-1.14.1/doc/aclocal-1.14.1
```

This should disable help2man invoking for automake building. Yes, it's a bit ugly and it'd better to fix real issue but enough to keep going and build image.

Comment: Thanks for this response, and now I have got errors in native ncurses. I have re-edited the question for the same.