# Buildroot fails to build images for intel edison in ubuntu 17.10 (64 bit)

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot, intel-edison, ubuntu-17.10

I am trying to build images for Intel Edison board.

But it fails while configuring lzop on Ubuntu 17.10.

I have linked [Build Error logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q5DLGg0DkKPTYFXWUiVvbNEqGGvCekNi) and [config.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kj9vcr-VzGq8mU-4TstdhrDyHLczAIsY) for the same.

INPUT : 
       I did following procedure.

make edison_defconfig.

make

Thanks,

Pritam

Comment: Stack Overflow requires logs which describes the problem to be **in the question post**, not linked. In case the log is large you may post only some lines (usually, which contains error message described the first error), while giving link to the complete log. [edit] your question and add the error information into it. The same is true for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373815/yocto-fails-to-build-images-for-intel-edison-in-ubuntu-17-1064-bit).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are missing this commit to fix compatibility with >= gcc 6.x:
https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/?id=040c9e14edeab0c6173f72c0a1e765fc5a3a58ea

This was added during the 2016.08 cycle, so it must mean you are using an older version than that. Please upgrade to a supported version (2017.02.9 or 2017.11.2) to fix this and lots of other issues.

Comment: Thanks, This patch worked for me. I had to patch this with edison supported buildroot.